# Geolocation help for ip adress search?

Tags: php, geolocation

I'm trying to create a system in my website using geolocation that shows the user his location and stuff about him. I'm trying to implement a search like thing, which will search for other people's geolocation who have a longitude and lattitude almost the same as you, and will display their name. I've tryed googling it, searching it, with no luck. I've found a search bar in php, how to do geolocation, but not how to put them together. Thanks

Comment: You can use HTML5 Geolocation functionality to get the location of one user but it asks for user to allow this function or deny. Now, after that you have to know the locations of other who should allow to track their location. Lastly, they all should be connected via one application like Facebook. There are some other complexities but once you begin learning this you will get to know. Other mehtod would be the use of ip address to track location. You may get country level tracking for free upto certain extent but city level tracking needs money.

Comment: my cell phones ip based location is fixed to my cell carriers HQ, my work ip to the head office, the home pc, bounces around based on the ISP. so its mostly useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geolocation by IP is not reliable. IP addresses don't correlate to locations, they only correlate to networks.

Based on the known location of a network you can guess where the user is, but while some networks cover only a city or part of it, others cover multiple countries at once. There is no way to know with reliable precision where you really are just by IP.

Comment: I think you mean "reliable"?

Comment: Okay, thanks! WHat I meant was longitude and lattitude not ip adress. Sorry! How would I be able to do it based on lonhitude and lattitude?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this's everything you need.
I complated a short script to get information of ips that visited my website.
It can get country, city,ip address, flag of country, coordinates on google map, links that visitor visited.
You can understand and download when read this link : [IP Geolocation](http://www.code4share.net/items/php-script-get-ips-information-that-accessing-your-website/XRGXV6u.html#)

Good luck to you.